# Emulated DJI Mobile SDK keeps

Tags: java, android, dji-sdk

In the context of an university project, we want to develop an Android app (Java) using the DJI Mobile SDK (4.11) to control a DJI Mavic 2.

Our created/ downloaded apps like the DJI [SDK samples](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-Android) can be run on mobile phones after building them as APKs but we didn´t accomplish to emulate them in Android Studio (3.5.1). Already read that it wouldn´t be possible but developing an app without testing it in the IDE won´t be practicable for us...

Is there any option?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The DJI SDK doesn´t work with the ARM86 architecture. Had to switch to an V7a version (virtual device setting), emulation is working now!

Answer (score 0):

The best option,  and one I tend to leverage is use the simulator.   I almost bench fly more than I fly outside.

I cannot think of another option of hand.